# Python dump JSON object into another JSON object

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm making a program that generates a JSON file with JSON objects. But I'm having some trouble with making a valid JSON file.

My goal is to make a valid JSON object (See example below) dynamically.

So you start with a empty JSON object: `{ }`. Then the toruble comes with this: Add a JSON Object:

```
{
    "Description": "just a making a object",
    "Duration": "ongoing",
    "Image": null,
    "Process": null,
    "day": "Saturday",
    "end": "11:32:34.453694",
    "start": "11:32:31.700324"
}
```

To that empty JSON object Like this:

```
{
    "MonTask1": {
        "Description": "just a making a object",
        "Duration": "ongoing",
        "Image": null,
        "Process": null,
        "day": "Saturday",
        "end": "11:32:34.453694",
        "start": "11:32:31.700324"
    },
    "MonTask2": { 
        "Description": "just a making a object",
        "Duration": "ongoing",
        "Image": null,
        "Process": null,
        "day": "Saturday",
        "end": "11:32:34.453694",
        "start": "11:32:31.700324"
    }
}
```

Is there a way in python3 to accomplish this?

My code is really simple:

```
def setTask(Day, Time, Description, Duration = None, Process = None, Image = None):
        task = {'day': Day, 'start': Time[0], 'end': Time[1], 'Description': Description, 'Duration': Duration, 'Process': Process, 'Image': Image}
        return task

import json

class jsonObject:

def __init__(self, path):
    self.filePath = path
    with open(self.filePath, 'w') as jsonFile:
        print('File was succesfully created!')

# task is the object made with the setTask method. 
# Path is the filePath for the JSON file
def writeToFile(self, task, path):
    jsonFile = open(path + '.json', 'a+')
    json.dump(task, jsonFile, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you generating the JSON and what trouble did you encounter? Are you aware that Python has builtin JSON support in the form of the ˋjsonˋ module?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I'm aware I used it. I edited the question with some more information.

Comment: Then you should be dealing with a regular dict to which you can add key/value pairs, and which you can nest in other containers. Can you please show how you are doing this? It is generally a pretty basic task in Python, so it is unclear what problem you have without some code.

Comment: I added some code @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Your setTask already creates a JSON object (dict) containing other data. What trouble do you have creating a JSON object containing the data created by setTask in the same way? Apologies for keeping on asking, but you seem to be practically already doing what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Python dictionary with the structure equivalent to json you need.
Below is the excerpt from python shell:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a'] = {}
>>> d['a']['b'] = 1
>>> d
{'a': {'b': 1}}
>>> d['a']['c'] = 2
>>> d
{'a': {'c': 2, 'b': 1}}
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"a": {"c": 2, "b": 1}}'
>>> j = json.dumps(d)
>>> open('/tmp/a.txt','w').write(j)
23
>>> 
$ cat /tmp/a.txt 
{"a": {"c": 2, "b": 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

After parsing, you have a regular Python object, which you can embed into `dict`s, and so on. Then pack the result back into JSON.

```
import json

basejson='''{
    "Description": "just a making a object",
    "Duration": "ongoing",
    "Image": null,
    "Process": null,
    "day": "Saturday",
    "end": "11:32:34.453694",
    "start": "11:32:31.700324"
}'''
parsedobject=json.loads(basejson)

compoundobject={'MonTask1':parsedobject,'MonTask2':parsedobject}

prettyjson=json.dumps(compoundobject,indent=4)

print(prettyjson)
```

The result is what you have in the question.